# Scala pattern matching '@'/at bind operator fails to preserve type narrowing

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I want to narrow a type when I'm pattern matching in order to special case it, but when trying to bind the tuple I'm pattern matching against to a variable, the Scala compiler seems to lose the type narrowing performed in the match. This prevents me from just forwarding the match and instead I have to recreate the tuple so that the types are preserved.

Minified example:

```scala
sealed trait Fruit
case class Apple(weight: Int = 200) extends Fruit
case object Orange extends Fruit

object PatternBinding extends App {
  def handleApple(appleWithIndex: (Apple, Int)) =
    println(s"Apple with weight: ${appleWithIndex._1}")

  def handleFruit(fruitWithIndex: (Fruit, Int)) =
    println("Other fruit")

  val seq = Seq[Fruit](Apple(120), Orange, Orange, Apple())

  seq.zipWithIndex.foreach {
    case tup @ (apple: Apple, index) =>
      handleApple(tup) // <------------ does not compile
//      handleApple((apple, index)) // compiles
    case tup @ (fruit, index) => handleFruit(tup)
  }
}
```

Is there some reason for this or just a peculiar corner case?

Is there an existing issue which I may track? I tried searching, but came up empty handed.

The compiler error message:

```
    type mismatch;  found   : (Fruit, Int)  required: (Apple, Int)
```

In essence I would have expected the `Apple` case to be transformed in to something like this pseudo-scala:

```
case tup : (Apple, Int) @ (apple: Apple, index) =>
```

With `tup` having the type `(Apple, Int)`.

Scala fiddle example: http://scalafiddle.net/console/f182c4c2e7b4bd91debd2d0d636becac

Scala version is 2.11.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The spec says](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#constructor-patterns) the type params are instantiated to conform to the expected type of the pattern. That's how you know in turn what the expected types of the nested "component patterns" are.

So it's outside-in, not inside-out.

I wonder if tuple optimization could work for this case.

The [issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8790) says, If I create a tuple just to deconstruct it, don't bother constructing it.

This would add, if I deconstruct a tuple just to construct it, just reuse the instance, even though it's a different tuple type.

In other words, avoid reboxing the int and the tuple for `(x,i)`:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

sealed trait Fruit
case class Apple(weight: Int = 200) extends Fruit
case object Orange extends Fruit
val fruits = Seq[Fruit](Apple(120), Orange, Orange, Apple())

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait Fruit
defined class Apple
defined object Orange
fruits: Seq[Fruit] = List(Apple(120), Orange, Orange, Apple(200))

scala> fruits.zipWithIndex map { case (x: Apple, i: Int) => (x,i) case _  => (null, -1) }
res0: Seq[(Apple, Int)] = List((Apple(120),0), (null,-1), (null,-1), (Apple(200),3))
```

I appended the use case to the ticket, since tuples are special creatures and will be final soon.

Comment: "...outside-in, not inside-out...": That clarifies it. `tup`s type is already determined to be of the type which is matched against. The refinement that the first element actually is an `Apple` is all well and dandy, but won't affect the type of `tup` which is already determined to be `(Fruit, Int)`. It does seem like the compiler could, in theory, safely cast `tup` to be of the "refined" type though.

Thumbs up to the new(?) web spec btw! Last time I looked it was a downloadable pdf.

Comment: Yah, a few ppl worked rally hard on the web spec. I wonder if they could spec `x @` as currently and `x @@ (_: Apple, _)` to mean type x in the way you want. Doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: Great work with the spec indeed! It would be interesting to know what, if anything, would break if `x @` would become more specific. About `x @@`: yes, it would be nice. Don't know how it would compare to other things feature budget wise though...

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that `apple: Apple` is just a test that checks `apple.isInstanceOf[Apple]` and assigns the value to the `apple` variable. However, it doesn't change the type of `tup` which is `Pair[Fruit, Int]` (or, equivalently, `(Fruit, Int)`). (Additional traits `Product with Serializable` come from the keyword `case` in declaration of `Orange` and `Apple`.)

(Actually, `Seq(Apple(120), Orange, Orange, Apple())` has the type `Seq[T]` where `T` is the lowest super type of the sequence elements. That super type `T` contains `Fruit` of course. However, the keyword `case` adds additional types `Product with Serializable` automatically to both `Apple` and `Orange`, but not to `Fruit`. That's why the calculated type `T` has some more type information. If you wish, you may remove the exhaustive types by ascribing type of an element of the sequence: `Seq(Apple(120):Fruit, Orange, Orange, Apple())`. It will have type `Seq[Fruit]`.).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Arseniy. I've edited the code and question to remove the `Product with Serializable` type inference thing which really was a minor issue. I was more interested in the `apple.isInstanceOf[Apple]` check which doesn't seem to transfer that "type evidence" to the `tup` variable.